# Build pojo with two Jsons

Tags: java, android, android-volley, retrofit

I'm doing an application with the MVP pattern and I have a question that could solve a number of ways but I would like to know which is the best ever.

My POJO is created with a request to JSON and JSON data that another request to complete it is.

I'm using Volley. In my repository I have a method "getNewCats ()" and within the OnRespose call another method of my repository called "completeCats (List  cats)" completes the arraylist of cats.

The problem is that if the answer of "completeCats (List  cats)" takes a long time, in the reciclerView objects appear incomplete pojo

How would you do a request cascaded?

I only work with JSON since for the images use Glide. Recomend use Reteofit?

Comment: The best way to solve this problem is to have a single api call to get complete data from server. This issue is not related to use of retrofit or any other library. You can have async call these 2 api to improve response time if second is not dependent on first api. For you problem you can provide data to adapter after both request completed. (I mean provide complete data only, not partial data from one request)

Comment: Thank you very much! As if I needed the first request for the second I made a " AsyncTask " called " AsyncDownloader " where I do 2 http client with " OkHttp3 " . Now only I would not implement the methods in " AsyncDownloader " and do the " Repository " my master MVP overwriting the " doInBackground " method and " onPostExecute " in order to use my class for many types of requests both PUT and GET, but that it is no longer a problem I guess.